# Delete rows where matched value is twice as much

Tags: mysql, delete, mysqli

I'm trying to match two tables with two columns, `table1` and `table2`.
Each has `id` and `price` columns.

I want the query to match each `id` and compare the `price`, then delete the row if the `price` in the second table is twice as much as the other one.

My query up to now ( does not work ):

```
include ('go.php');
$sql = "delete 
from table1
where table1.id IN 
    (select table2.id where table1.price > table2.price*2)"
or die(mysqli_error($sql));
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You have not run the query; you have merely set `$sql`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to `DELETE` all the information in `table1.*`:

```
DELETE table1.*
FROM test.table1
JOIN test.table2 ON (table2.id = table1.id)
WHERE table1.price < (table2.price*2);
```

This will `DELETE` all rows from `table1` that match with the `WHERE` criteria. If you want to `DELETE` all the rows that match against the `WHERE` criteria in `table2`, just replace `DELETE table1.*` to `DELETE table2.*`.

As the MySQL's [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/delete.html) says:

**Multi-Table Deletes**

> You can specify multiple tables in a DELETE
>   statement to delete rows from one or more tables depending on the
>   condition in the WHERE clause. You cannot use ORDER BY or LIMIT in a
>   multiple-table DELETE. The table_references clause lists the tables
>   involved in the join, as described in Section 13.2.9.2, “JOIN Syntax”.
>
> For the first multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the
>   tables listed before the FROM clause are deleted. For the second
>   multiple-table syntax, only matching rows from the tables listed in
>   the FROM clause (before the USING clause) are deleted. The effect is
>   that you can delete rows from many tables at the same time and have
>   additional tables that are used only for searching:

```
 DELETE t1, t2 FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 WHERE t1.id=t2.id
 AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

> Or:

```
 DELETE FROM t1, t2 USING t1 INNER JOIN t2 INNER JOIN t3 WHERE
 t1.id=t2.id AND t2.id=t3.id;
```

> If you use a multiple-table DELETE statement involving InnoDB tables
>   for which there are foreign key constraints, the MySQL optimizer might
>   process tables in an order that differs from that of their
>   parent/child relationship. In this case, the statement fails and rolls
>   back. Instead, you should delete from a single table and rely on the
>   ON DELETE capabilities that InnoDB provides to cause the other tables
>   to be modified accordingly.
>
> Note If you declare an alias for a table, you must use the alias when
>   referring to the table:

```
 DELETE t1 FROM test AS t1, test2 WHERE ...
```

> Table aliases in a multiple-table DELETE should be declared only in
>   the table_references part of the statement. Elsewhere, alias
>   references are permitted but not alias declarations.